# hide form scrollbar in C#

Tags: c#, forms, scrollbar, hide

Maybe this isn't a new question; but unfortunately I'm unable to solve my problem.

My Form needs to show scrollbar, but I don't want use scrollbar all the time. 
I want to know how to show the ScrollBar only in specific conditions.

For example: 
I want to set specific Form Position without using / showing the scrollbar when form is out of working area boundaries.

Thus my question: How to move Form Horizontally without using scrollbar?

**Update:** It seems still my question is unclear.
Please find bellow the following conditions:

1. Form requires ScrollBar functionality when the form border is smaller than the page.
2. Show ScrollBar when the Form is out of Working Area boundaries.

I wait for your useful replies!

Comment: does this position is within the form like its y is within height and x is within width?

Comment: And we wait for useful details.

Comment: Put all the controls on a Panel.  Change the panel's Location property to fake the scroll.

Comment: @HansPassant you should put that as an answer, as it should solve the problem

Comment: @ivowiblo - I fear words like "more explain please".  If you want to take a stab at an answer then please feel free to use my comment.

Comment: :D special thanks!! I realy confused, I thought that i said clearly about my question...

Comment: if you are online please answer to my questions step by step to unederstand better my problem. of course if you want? or have time?

Comment: ok I add my questions on my main post. I HOPE that's help you to understant at least! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the AutoScroll to false and then update the scroll values programmatically:

```
this.HorizontalScroll.Value = this.HorizontalScroll.Maximum;
```

Comment: special thanks @John Koerner
! but still I have a question. for refering to a point. for example a panel location. what should I do? like: ' this.HorizontalScroll.Value = panel2.Location.X; '

Comment: Have you tried using the ScrollControlIntoView() method on the form, to scroll to a particular control?  You can set the scrolloffset on the control to manage how far the scroll should go.

Comment: no. I didn't use ScrollControlIntoView() till now. but it seems I need to read more about scrollbar property. many many thanks for your response! :)

Comment: I searched in the net but i didn't find out good rusult about managing scrollbar. Can you give me a sample code to show how can set the HorizontalScroll.Value with a control position?!